# Wordpress Deadlock Error

Tags: mysql, rewrite-rules, options

I see more of this error these days in error_log. I see that someone asked this question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147627/strange-deadlock-database-error-for-the-query-delete-from-wp-options) a year ago but no solution. Please advise what is causing this issue. Already, tried deactivating some plugins like w3total cache, disabled a few options like minify on w3total cache but nothing helped. Also, the site is using cloudfront, optimized. please advise.

```
WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` = 'rewrite_rules' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('wp_loaded'), call_user_func_array, WP_Rewrite->flush_rules, delete_option, W3_Db->query, W3_DbCache->query, W3_DbCallUnderlying->query, W3_Db->query, W3_DbProcessor->query, W3_Db->default_query
```

Comment: i added this function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/flush_rules/#source-code after reading this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-deadlock-on-table-while-flushing-rewrite-rules but don't know if it solves the issue yet.

Comment: no one faced this error?

Comment: I see tons of these errors in our logs right now. The server keeps crashing because of this.